# How to complain about a user?

Tags: support, users, offensive

I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881045/android-notification-works-for-one-object-in-a-loop) and a user was rude to me in a comment and in an answer. Even though I can't downvote, that answer got -5 and it was automatically deleted. I want to complain about that user. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't post here. You flag the comments.

Comment: i flag, and it seems many also flags so stackoverflow delete that comments and that answer

Comment: So, what's the problem? What would complaining add, except make _you_ feel better?

Comment: If the user is abusive, repeatedly, they will be dealt with. One occurrence is not enough.

Comment: he hurts me a lot, i am asking if stackoverflow punish those people

Comment: That's now how it works. And you need to grow a thicker skin if you are going to post on the Internet - not all people are nice and you need to learn to live with it (anonymity makes some people not care about civility). Like I said, a single incident is not normally enough.

Comment: Just to say that most people who read the posts (including the deleted one) will not see someone being overly rude. He is expressing an opinion, strongly and is disagreeing with you - and you know? That's OK.

Comment: @Oded he deleted the bad words, really, he said `shame on me` to not follow his answer, then he delete it in comment, he said also bad words in the answer but he edit the question, now you will not see the deleted bad words

Comment: Since when is "shame on you" rude? It is an opinion and he actually said "shame you don't...". As for me not seeing deleted content - I am a moderator and _can_ see it.

Comment: if it is not bad words why he deleted it, also for me it is bad words, also in the question he said bad words, please if you are admin here please see the answer he deleted

Comment: I will say this again. Disagreeing with you is **not** rude. And that's all this user did. They did **not** use foul language and perhaps were not super polite, but this is far from being rude. You need to take some time away from the computer, calm down and relax.

Comment: As for comments being deleted - if they are not constructive to the conversation (the question/answer) they should be deleted. Doesn't matter what words they contain.

Comment: @Oded thank you very much. i appreciated ur efforts. i will take care of your notes

Comment: @user2387331 There is a reason I made those edits. There is no need to call out a specific user here on Meta. You can ask the generic question and get a generic answer detailing what to do. Please leave the question in its current state.

Comment: One issue might be one of a language barrier: "shame on you" is very different than "shame you don't".

Comment: If you take offense and get hurt so much then maybe Stack Overflow is not the place for you. One should expect some criticism when posting in this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user is verbally abusive or rude, **flag** whatever they've posted - or bring it to a diamond moderator's attention in the "Flag Question/Answer" dialog.

If it's excessive and egregious, it will be dealt with.

Comment: @Oded please how could I find those users? maybe like this sign right of your name ?

Comment: @user2387331 - Yes. And you don't go out to "find" them, as there is no PM functionality here. You flag a comment/answer/question for "Moderator attention".

Comment: I hope I did that before the question is deleted

Comment: @user2387331 - I should make a note that one thing you absolutely *cannot* do is use you and five of your friends to coordinate offensive flags in order to target an answer for destruction, like was done here. This is an abuse of the flagging system, and we do not tolerate this.